# Identity server /connect/token giving empty 500 error - how can I find error message?

Tags: identityserver4

I have an Identity Server 4 application hosted in IIS which I've deployed to a new environment (the same code is working fine in other environments). When a separate app hits the `/connect/token` endpoint it returns a 500, but without any content. How can I find the error which is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within IIS Manager, open the Identity Server app. Click on Configuration Editor, and look at the `system.webServer/aspNetCore` section. Change `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` if it's not already, then hit the endpoint again. The `stdoutLogFile` setting shows where the log files will be (if they are in a folder you may need to create the folder manually). The log file will contain the exception message and stack trace.